# Sync OneDrive with GoogleDrive with Office365 autosave enabled

Tags: onedrive, google-drive

My organisation is using Google Drive as its main cloud file sharing.

With GSuite, I have Google Drive File Stream installed, which setup a new drive on Microsoft (10) under Drive G.

My department also uses Office 365 personal edition, just enough to allow Autosave and Version History features, as Google office equivalent cannot compete with MS in terms of performance and capability.

Now I haven't found a way to sync my OneDrive with Google Drive File Stream in such a way I can enable auto-save and version history features of MS Office. These can only be enabled if the file is located inside a One-Drive folder.

Is there a way?

Comment: Move the OneDrive folder to within the local directory used by Google Drive to sync.  Sign out of the OneDrive application, sign back in, then choose a custom location for the OneDrive folder (it may be under an option like Manual or Advanced in the OneDrive setup walkthrough.  To avoid OneDrive re-syncing all data, prior to signing back into OneDrive, cut/paste the OneDrive folder into the Google Drive sync directory, then choose the new path to the OneDrive folder in the OneDrive application.

Comment: Thanks @JW0914 This is the first thing I tried but OneDrive won’t accept the G: drive as a location.

Comment: Is the Google Drive sync located at the root of `G:` (i.e. `G:\ ` is the sync directory, syncing everything contained within `G:\ `), or is located within a folder at the root `G:` (i.e. `G:\GoogleDrive`)?  Does OneDrive provide an error when you're trying to select `G:\GoogleDrive\OneDrive` as the sync directory during OneDrive setup?

Comment: Alright I got it. So Google created the G: drive and added *My Drive* and *Shared Drive* into it and it refused. So I tried to locate OneDrive in G: and I can locate it in G:\My Drive\, however now it says it is not able to sync and try later. I'll give it a try later and see what's up.

Comment: I haven't used Google Drive's Windows application for some time, but it used to offer the same customization option under Manual or Advanced during its setup that allowed the user to select a custom location (it was tiny and easy to miss during setup).  I would try that as [from your explanation] `G:` isn't a physical drive and is likely why OneDrive is rejecting the path _(i.e. change Google Drive's sync folder location to a physical drive path, then once it's setup finishes, try adding OneDrive's sync folder to that directory)_.